# What is the graveyard compaction in cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0, cassandra-cli

Cassandra noob here. While going through the documentation etc, I'm repetitevely finding references to graveyard compaction (and occasionally tombstones), example:

```
$ cassandra-cli 
[default@unknown] help truncate;
...
A snapshot of the data is created, which is deleted asyncronously during a
'graveyard' compaction.
```

I've tried googling around, but that just turns up more places where graveyard compaction is referred, examples [this](http://www.ukessays.com/essays/engineering/structure-and-apis-for-cassandra-engineering-essay.php), [this](http://marc.info/?l=cassandra-user&m=133291986931370) and [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/commits@cassandra.apache.org/msg100761.html).

What exactly is the graveyard compaction? And what do people mean when they refer to tombstones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Graveyard compaction is a compaction that deletes SSTables that are no longer needed.

For instance during a drop, after the snapshot is made, the sstables of the respective table are deleted by a graveyard compaction.

```
A snapshot of the data is created, which is deleted asyncronously during a
'graveyard' compaction.
```

What you found here is just an error in the documentation. It should say:

```
A snapshot of the data is created, 
then the data is deleted asyncronously during a 'graveyard' compaction.
```